# Flutter Web Status request

Tags: flutter, dart, http, web

I want to make a status query of my web server for my website which I program with Flutter, which is green when the server is reachable and red when not.
With my current code I always get a "XMLHttpRequest" error.

[server_api.dart](https://codeshare.io/zyBB1j)

I have already tried it by simple pinging but have also come to no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try these headers

```
get headers => {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  };
```